# Report Migration: Crystal Reports (Rpt) to Sql Reports (Rdl)

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

Is there free software that converts Crystal Reports .rpt files to SQL Reporting 2008 .rdl files?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396/easy-way-for-crystal-reports-to-ms-sql-server-reporting-services-conversion

Comment: see [RptToXml](http://code.google.com/p/rpttoxml/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll quickly find out that this isn't allowed due to Crystal licensing restrictions. There are several companies that offer RPT to RDL conversion services for different costs, but free software for this purpose is not available.

Comment: This is because Crystal Reports is deprecated as of 2013 and SSRS is actively developed on and will see a huge Power BI enhancement in 2016 along with other features. If you want to port your reports over take the SQL out and remake the reports.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.rpttordl.com. It's not software, but a service. You have a couple of options there with them.